# how to replace a character within in a multiple double quoted words within a line using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have text file including text format like this.

```
012345,"[ThinkPadT2/3Gband,Mac]",Lenovo,"iPhone3G,A1241"
```

How do i replace comma inside words only within double quote by pipe(|) operator using sed. I need output like this :

```
012345,"[ThinkPadT2/3Gband | Mac]",Lenovo,"iPhone3G|A1241"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is standard procedure to make `sed` *non-greedy* and *back-reference* tip for substring(s) in brackets `()`

```
sed 's/\(\"[^",]\{1,\}\),\([^",]\{1,\}\"\)/\1 | \2/g'
```

Or for GNU `sed`

```
sed -r 's/("[^",]+),([^",]+")/\1 | \2/g'
```

Comment: Do we need to escape the double quotes?

Comment: @muru Yes, you are right, it is overcautious. Made edition.

Comment: This assumes that each quoted string contains ***exactly*** one comma. It fails on `012345,"[ThinkPadT2/3Gband-Mac]",Lenovo,"iPhone3G,A1241"` and `012345,"[ThinkPadT2,3Gband,Mac]",Lenovo,"iPhone3G,A1241"`.

Comment: @Costas where is your edit?

Comment: @AvinashRaj In my post.

Comment: your code fails to replace `,` in `"[ThinkPadT2,3Gband,Mac]"` string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Let answer which `,` should be exchanged, first or second? I decide no one as *only single comma would be replaced between quotes*. If you have other opinion you are free to offer your own script.

Comment: @Costas posted, but it's a perl oneliner.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$ cat filename
012345,"[ThinkPadT2/3Gband,Mac]",Lenovo,"iPhone3G,A1241"

$ cat filename | sed -E 's:([A-Z,a-z]),([A-Z,a-z]):\1|\2:g'
012345,"[ThinkPadT2/3Gband|Mac]",Lenovo,"iPhone3G|A1241"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed is not the right tool for this. I think it may require some advanced features to achieve like the above. Here is the perl on-liner which replaces any number of double commas present within double quotes with `<space>|<space>` .

```
$ echo '012345,"[ThinkPadT2/3Gband,Mac,Apple]",Lenovo,"iPhone3G,A1241"' | perl -pe 's/,(?!(?:"[^"]*"|[^"])*$)/ | /g'
012345,"[ThinkPadT2/3Gband | Mac | Apple]",Lenovo,"iPhone3G | A1241"
```

Comment: While not sed, this is helpful, as stated, for cases where multiple commas shows in the quotes.